# Two tables, two relationships

Tags: mysql, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have two tables; agency and user.

In most cases, a user will belong to an Agency otherwise will be null. This relationship is quite straightforward to model, I have a nullable agency_id column/property in the user entity class/table.

An agency also has to have an admin user. An agency can have more than one admin user. I am struggling to model this relationship.

How can I represent the second relationship in my entity classes/database tables? I am working with Doctrine 2 (MySQL), Symfony 3 and FOSUserbundle.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you are looking for [One-To-Many Bidirectional](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) association mapping where on `OneToMany` association (in your `Agency` entity) you will have `users` collection and on `ManyToOne` association the `agencyId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to model this with OneToMany relations ships using Doctrine. Both users and admins are essentially the them relation (at least if you one user can only be admin of one agency, otherwise this needs to be a ManyToMany reference).

Information about Doctrine Associations can be found here:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

The following is some untested code that should show the associations:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Agency {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="agency")
     *
     * @var $users \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
     protected $users;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="adminOfAgency")
     *
     * @var $users \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
     protected $admins;

     public function __construct() {
          $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
          $this->admins = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
     }

}
```

.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User extends \FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Agency", inversedBy="users")
     * @JoinColumn(name="agency_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     protected $agency;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Agency", inversedBy="admins")
     * @JoinColumn(name="admin_of_agency_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
     protected $adminOfAgency;

}
```